# Solve differential equation using superscript notation with DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

It appears `DSolve` won't accept a differential equation (DE) in superscript notation. How can I change the DE below so `DSolve` can solve it?

I am given a DE

```
diffeq = D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] - 2 D[u[x, t], x].
```

I apply a coordinate transform and the DE becomes the heat equation:

```
diffeq = (diffeq /. 
      u -> (u[#1 - v #2, #2] &) /. {x -> \[Epsilon] + v t} // 
    FullSimplify) /. v -> 2
```

The result of the transformation expresses derivatives using superscript notation and throws an error when I try to solve it with `DSolve`

```
DSolve[diffeq, u[\[Epsilon], t], {\[Epsilon], t}]
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: It doesn't really throw an error. It returns the unevaluated input.

Comment: In V12.1.1, I get the warning, "DSolve::lpde: General solution is not available for the given linear partial differential equation. Trying to build a special solution," and it returns `{{u[\[Epsilon], t] -> 1 + Cosh[C[1] + \[Epsilon] C[2] + t C[2]^2] + Sinh[C[1] + \[Epsilon] C[2] + t C[2]^2]}}`, if that's any help.  What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using V12.0.0.